# Discord Client Bot not responding the right way? Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

**ANSWER:**

So I did something else from the Question down bellow, I actually did not use the `.JSON` File and tried this:

**Prefixes.py** (File in Cogs):

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):

        mention = f'<@!{self.client.user.id}>'
        if mention in message.content:
            prefix = await self.client.get_prefix(message)
            try:
                x = ""
                pfp = self.client.user.avatar_url
                prefix = discord.Embed(title=x, description=f"My prefix for **{message.guild.name}** is `{prefix}`. If you want to find out more information about me type `{prefix}help`.", color = 0x456383)
                prefix.set_footer(text=f"ChizLanks", icon_url=pfp)
                await message.channel.send(embed = prefix)
            except discord.Forbidden:
                return await message.channel.send(f"My prefix for **{message.guild.name}** is `{prefix}`. If you want to find out more information about me type `{prefix}help`")
```

What I did is that, I added the `prefix = await self.client.get_prefix(message)`. This will get the prefix from the `.JSON` File or if the `.JSON` File is empty it will use the Default Prefix `/` which can be found in the `Main.py` File. This worked fine for me and it should be working fine for you too. What I have in my Main file can be found down here:

**Main.py**:

```
def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as file:
        prefixes = json.load(file)

    if str(message.guild.id) in prefixes:
        return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

    else:
        return "/"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = get_prefix)
```

===========================================================================

**QUESTION:**

So I was making an `on_message` Event, so whenever someone mentioned the Client's ID, it would respond with a message which would have the Server Prefix on it. (I'm using a `per-server-prefix` system.) So I tried this:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):


        def botprefix(self, message):
            with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as file:
                prefixes = json.load(file)

            if str(message.guild.id) in prefixes:
                return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

            else:
                return "/"

        mention = f'<@!{self.client.user.id}>'
        if mention in message.content:
            try:
                x = ""
                pfp = self.client.user.avatar_url
                prefix = discord.Embed(title=x, description=f"My prefix for **{message.guild.name}** is `{botprefix}`. If you want to find out more information about me type `{botprefix}help`.", color = 0x456383)
                prefix.set_footer(text=f"ChizLanks", icon_url=pfp)
                await message.channel.send(embed = prefix)
            except discord.Forbidden:
                return await message.channel.send(f"My prefix for **{message.guild.name}** is `{botprefix}`. If you want to find out more information about me type `{botprefix}help`")
```

But it seems it was not working correctly, and whenever I mentioned the bot this would show up[image]

Could anyone explain why this is not working and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a function to generate the prefix which means you need to call it first to actually get the prefix. Here's the change you need to make:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):


    def botprefix(self, message):
        with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as file:
            prefixes = json.load(file)

        if str(message.guild.id) in prefixes:
            return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

        else:
            return "/"

    mention = f'<@!{self.client.user.id}>'
    if mention in message.content:
        prefix = botprefix(message) # Calculate the bot prefix for this guild
        try:
            x = ""
            pfp = self.client.user.avatar_url
            prefix = discord.Embed(title=x, description=f"My prefix for **{message.guild.name}** is `{prefix}`. If you want to find out more information about me type `{prefix}help`.", color = 0x456383)
            prefix.set_footer(text=f"ChizLanks", icon_url=pfp)
            await message.channel.send(embed = prefix)
        except discord.Forbidden:
            return await message.channel.send(f"My prefix for **{message.guild.name}** is `{prefix}`. If you want to find out more information about me type `{prefix}help`")
```

I stored the result of `botprefix(message)` in `prefix` then used that in the f-strings.

---

### READ ME

What I have done above is a quick and dirty fix to your code. **However**, you should make some changes to your bot. First of all, you should move `botprefix()` out of the `on_message` function then when you declare your bot, use it as the `command_prefix` argument like so:

```py
def get_prefix(bot, message):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as file:
        prefixes = json.load(file)

    if str(message.guild.id) in prefixes:
        return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

    else:
        return "/"


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix)
```

**You can find more about calculating dyanamic prefixes [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=command_prefix#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command_prefix).**

Comment: Sorry for this late response, So I tried this but still it did not work and it gave me the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\irdio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\irdio\Desktop\ChizLanksPY\cogs\Event_Handler.py", line 56, in on_message
    prefix = botprefix(message) # Calculate the bot prefix for this guild
TypeError: botprefix() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'` Am I missing something?

Comment: @xXSkillexZ Which function are you using, the first or the second? In the second one, you need to specify the bot as well. You can access that easily wil `self.bot`

Comment: I do not remember which one I was using but I found another way to get the prefix and I edited my answer to it, I will accept your question just in case someone needs it.